# Deducing explicitly specialized function template type

Tags: c++, gcc, c++14, language-lawyer, type-deduction

In [the following code](https://wandbox.org/permlink/h9wk6sNNDJjOm8K0) GCC fails to compile (1) (cannot deduce `F`), but successfully compiles (2). The key point here is the `bar` template's deduced return type, otherwise GCC wouldn't fail.

However, Clang compiles the whole code without an error.

What's the essential difference between (1) and (2) in this context, besides of being `b` a pointer to function?    Is it a bug in GCC, or there's something ill-formed here?

```
template<class>
auto bar() {
    return 0;
}

template<class F>
void foo(F&&) {
}

int main () {
    foo(bar<int>); // (1)

    auto b = bar<int>;
    foo(b);  // (2)
}
```

Comment: Looks like a GCC bug to me.  ICC and MSVS also both compile.

Comment: Yes, it is a gcc bug: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?format=multiple&id=64194

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it's a GCC bug which has been around for a while: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?format=multiple&id=64194

Comment: @IgorR., yeah, that's really frustrating. I guess, since there is a workaround, it is not high on their priority list.